# How to get database name from a connection?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdbdash

Using the driver rethinkdbdash...

Given:

`const rConnection = r.db('someDb').table('someTable')`

How do I get the **database name** or the **table name** this connection is using from the variable `rConnection`?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40025181/how-to-get-the-database-and-table-name-from-a-reql-query/40156003#40156003), here's an ugly solution that works (tested on rethinkdb, not rethinkdbdash):

```js
nesh> let mom = (q, fn) => q.toString().match(new RegExp(fn + '\\(\\"(.*?)\\"\\)'))[1]
undefined
nesh> rql = r.db('foo').table('bar')
nesh> mom(rql, 'db')
'foo'
nesh> mom(rql, 'table')
'bar'
```